# Firefox does not render .svg properly

Tags: debugging, svg, firefox, cross-browser

I manage a blog where I use .svg files as illustrations, you can see a live example here: https://salarship.com/article/dress-fast-food-job-interview/

The problem is that the .svg files do not render properly on Firefox. Here is [how the image looks on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pRND.png) and [how it looks on other browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9WKd.png). Here is the raw file of the image: https://salarship.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/wear-job-interview-fast-food.svg

Is it a problem with this particular file, how can I fix it? I have hundreds of articles with this problem, is there a way to fix each image relatively quickly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a path in there with the following command sequence (shortened for clarity):

```
... v 0 a 0.25,0.25 0 0 0 0,0.07 0.19,0.19 0 0 1 0,0.07 8.510071e11,8.510071e11 0 0 1 0,0.18 ...
```

The arc command with radius `8.510071e11` seems to throw Firefox. That is a bug.

since an arc with such a large radius is straight anyway, the sequence could be changed such that a `v` line command is used instead:

```
... v 0 a 0.25,0.25 0 0 0 0,0.07 0.19,0.19 0 0 1 0,0.07 v 0.18 ...
```

Comment: That's perfect, it seems that most browsers and editors interpret very large numbers to be 0.However, Firefox interprets them as infinity, which gives different results...

Comment: Your interpretation makes no sense. A radius of Infinitiy makes the arc a straight line, while a radius of 0 could not be rendered. Browsers implement a [corrective algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#ArcOutOfRangeParameters) to achieve values that can be interpreted, so a value of 0 would always be replaced by the smallest possible radius (here: 0.09). Very large radii are not handled at this stage, because they should pose no problem. My hunch would be that the Firefox bug is at a later stage of the rendering pipeline.